# Zend Framework 2 error : Statement could not be executed when implement year function in table gateway

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have implemented tablegateway statements in my zf2 project but now I have problem when I used mysql year function couse I snipped it into `greaterThanOrEqualTo` function. this is my code

**code:**

```
$where = new Where();
$classYearMin = $classYear - 1;
$where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('year(date_a)', $classYear)
->and
->equalTo('id_type',1)
->and
->notEqualTo('semester_type','concat("B_","'.$classYearMin.'","/","'.$classYear.'")');
$sql= $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($where) {
    $select
    ->columns(array('semester_type'))
    ->order('date_a')
    ->where($where);
});
```

and my `mysql` output syntax :

**Syntax:**

```
select semester_type 
from skedul 
where year(date_a) >= 2010 
  and id_type = 1 
  and semester_type != concat('B_',2010-1,'/',2010) 
order by date_a;
```

and **error output**

> Statement could not be executed (42S22 - 1054 - Unknown column 'year`(`date_a`)' in 'where clause')

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Mysql output syntax i desired `select semester_type from skedul where year(date_a)>=2010 and id_type=1 and semester_type!=concat('B_',2010-1,'/',2010) order by date_a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default zend will assume that you are giving a column in `greaterOrEqualTo`. If you want to change that you need to use a Zend db expression.

Change

```
$where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('year(date_a)', $classYear)
```

With

```
$where->greaterThanOrEqualTo(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('year(date_a)'), $classYear)
```

By the way, you should print the real sql generated with ZF to find what does not work.

Hope this will solve the issue

Comment: Thank's @Unex its works and i have any idea to complete my work and i hope it works fine `$where = new Where();
$classYearMin = $classYear - 1;
$where->greaterThanOrEqualTo(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('year(date_a)'), $classYear)
->and
->equalTo('id_type',1)
->and
->notEqualTo('semester_type',new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('concat("B_","'.$classYearMin.'","/","'.$classYear.'")'));
$sql= $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($where) {
    $select
    ->columns(array('semester_type'))
    ->order('date_a')
    ->where($where);
});`